# jQuery Flexigrid hide column dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, flexigrid

There is a dropdown by default on each column which when expanded shows all the columns with checkbox.
I do not want to show the dropdowns in any of the columns.
Please tell me how to do that? Do I have to go into the script to remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the `showToggleBtn` option in flexigrid:

```
    $('#mygrid').flexigrid({
        showToggleBtn: false
    });
```

The best documentation for flexigrid is just opening up the [non-minified js](https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/blob/master/js/flexigrid.js) file, the options are right at the top and have some decent comments.

Comment: worked ... thanks !!
Also thanks for the help on documentation. I didn't know that.

Comment: No problem, make sure to mark the question as answered if you think it is.

Comment: True, I always forget about that :)